# FileManager.fileExistsAtPath prior to FileManager.removeItem?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

in iOS is it good practice to make sure a file exists before it is deleted, or is it fine to just go ahead and try to delete a file that may or may not exist and let the error fail silently in a catch block?

I'm iterating over a large list of local files to delete of which about 10% probably will not exist.

Comment: I honestly don't know. My instinct is to verify that the file exists before deleting it. I would suggest a test on your large file-set where you time it both ways and compare the results (on-device. Simulator tests are worthless for performance issues.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1415645-fileexistsatpath?language=objc) for the `fileExistsAtPath:` method:

> Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the file system or a particular file on the file system is not recommended. Doing so can cause odd behavior or race conditions. It’s far better to attempt an operation (such as loading a file or creating a directory), check for errors, and handle those errors gracefully than it is to try to figure out ahead of time whether the operation will succeed.